# Finding the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{1}{z-2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone help me out with finding the Laurent series of
$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{z-2}$ in $\{z \in \Bbb C: 2<|z-4|<3\}$?

Comment: The Laurent series in which annulus?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, I edited my post.

Comment: A [related technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174460/laurent-series-fz-frac1z2-4-frac16-z/174537#174537).

Comment: Just an addition to Mhenni's answer: You can obtain the power series for $\frac{1}{(1-w)^2}$ by taking the derivative of the series for $\frac{1}{(1-w)}$. (Be careful with the signs!)

Answer (score 1):

A [related technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228529/find-laurent-expansion-of-fracz-1z-2z-3-in-annulus-z2z3/228635#228635). Here is how you advance.

$$ f(z)=\dfrac{1}{(z-1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{z-2} =\dfrac{1}{((z-4)+3)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(z-4)+2}$$

$$ = \dfrac{1}{9\left(\frac{(z-4)}{3}+1\right)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(z-4)(1+\frac{2}{z-4})}  $$

$$ =  \dfrac{1}{9\left(w+1\right)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(z-4)(1+t)},  $$

where

> $$ w= \frac{(z-4)}{3}\,\quad  t= \frac{2}{z-4}. $$

Now, recalling the geometric series, we have, the power series of $g(w)=\frac{1}{(1+w)(1+w)}$ will converge for $|w|<1$ which implies 
$|z-4| <3 $. On the other hand, the power series $h(t)=\frac{1}{1+t}$ will converge for $|t|<1$ which gives $ |z-4|>2 $.