# How to expand $f(z)$ as a Laurent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Given

$$\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+2i)}$$

expand $f(z)$ in the following regions: $|z|<1$, $1<|z|<2$, $|z|>2$

I'm preparing for an exam and Laurent Series are a weakness of mine. I would love advice regarding interpretation, understanding, and solution of the problem.

Comment: Start with partial fraction!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal So after partial fractions I end up with $\frac{1}{5}(\frac{4+2i}{z+2i}+\frac{1-2i}{z-1})$

Comment: Use the geometric series to find the expansions according to the wanted intervals. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646696/finding-the-laurent-series-of-fz-frac1z-12-frac1z-2).

Comment: Indeed partial fractions:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+2i)} &=&a\frac{1}{z-1}+b\frac{1}{z+2i} \\
a &=&\frac{1}{1+2i},\;b=\frac{2i}{1+2i}
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a somewhat detailed description of the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ around $z=0$.

> The function
>
> \begin{align*}
>  f(z)&=\frac{z}{(z-1)(z+2i)}
>  =\frac{1-2i}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{4+2i}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{z+2i}\\
> \end{align*}
>    has two simple poles at $1$ and $-2i$.
>
> Since we want to find a Laurent expansion with center $0$, we look at the poles $1$ and $-2i$ and see they determine *three* regions.
>
> \begin{align*}
>  |z|<1,\qquad\quad
>  1<|z|<2,\qquad\quad
>  2<|z|
>  \end{align*}
>
> - The first region $ |z|<1$ is a disc with center $0$, radius $1$ and the pole $-2i$ at the boundary of the disc. In the *interior* of this disc all two fractions with poles $0$ and $-2i$  admit a representation as *power series* at $z=0$.
> - The second region $1<|z|<2$ is the annulus with center $0$, inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$. Here we have a representation of the fraction with pole $1$ as *[principal part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_part#Laurent_series_definition)* of a Laurent series at $z=0$, while the fraction with pole at $-2i$ admits a representation as power series.
> - The third region $|z|>2$ containing all points outside the disc with center $0$ and radius $2$ admits for all fractions a representation as principal part of a Laurent series at $z=0$.

A power series expansion of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is using *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{a}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{z}{a}}
=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{z}{a}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{a^{n+1}}z^n
\end{align*}
The principal part of $\frac{1}{z+a}$ at $z=0$ is
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{z+a}&=\frac{1}{z}\cdot\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{z}}
=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{a}{z}\right)^n
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-a)^n\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(-a\right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{z^n}
\end{align*}

> We can now obtain the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ for all three regions. Here we consider the second region
>
> - *Region 2:* $1<|z|<2$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(z)&=\frac{1-2i}{5}\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{4+2i}{5}\frac{1}{z+2i}\\
> &=\frac{1-2i}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}
> +\frac{4+2i}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2i)^{n+1}}z^{n}\\
> &=\frac{1-2i}{5}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}
> +\frac{4+2i}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{2i}\right)^nz^n\\
> &=\frac{1-2i}{5}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^n}
> +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^nz^n\right)\\
> \end{align*}

The other regions can be calculated similarly.

Comment: Shouldn't the pole $2i$ actually be $-2i$?

Comment: So for the region $|z|<1$, since none of $f(z)$'s singularities are involved I can use Taylor series to represent $f(z)$?

Comment: @Jay: Correct! ... and *two* principal part representations in the region $|z|>2$.

Comment: Great - also my answer for the second region agreed with yours, so I'm quite happy. Your explanation was extremely helpful. Thanks a ton!

Comment: One last question provided you have time: Could you explain the reasoning why two principal parts are necessary for the final region $|z|>2$?

Comment: @Jay: It depends on the analyticity due to the Cauchy Integral representation. See e.g. *[this paper](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/laurent.pdf)* example of section 4 and derivation in section 3. ... Btw. I'll remove some of my other comments in order to keep the number of comments small.